# How can I manipulate data in a PGFPlots Table using l3int?

Tags: pgfplotstable, expl3

I need to provide statistical functionality to some of my TeX-trainees and I'd like to leverage the intuitiveness of `l3int` and the expressiveness of `pgfplots` and its table helper package.

So, as a proof of concept, how might I take in an input file, sum the numbers in each row (appending the result), and then (the proof part of the concept) typeset it as a table?

Comment: Pgfplotstable has a section regarding the generation of new columns out of existing ones. In fact, I believe that it already has this very example. Nevertheless, the approach documented in the manual of pgfplotstable allows for a simple inclusion of any kind of TeX expression, including `l3int`. I'd suggest to study the section "Generating Data in New Tables or Columns" of http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf and ask more specific questions in case you run into problems.

Comment: Does @ChristianFeuersänger's comment answer your question?

Comment: @percusse if memory serves, yes. I'l write up a self-answer sometime today if I ever get these labs graded.

Comment: Hi Sean, would you like to answer this and get a badge for it? :P

Comment: @percusse Oh, my! Yes, I'll work on this today. I wonder if/where I have that document these days…

Comment: @SeanAllred Holy guacamole ! Time-machine stuff heheh

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.